# Address line 2 in Stripe Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

Using Stripes simple 'Checkout', is there a way to show a field for address_line2? When data-billingaddress="true" the popup form only shows one field for the customer's address.

```
<form action="charge.php" method="post">
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="test-key-goes-here"
      data-name="My Site Name"
      data-description="my product description"
      data-amount="5000"
      data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
      data-locale="auto"
      data-billingaddress="true"
      data-shippingaddress="false"
      data-currency="gbp">
</script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to accept `address_line2` in Checkout.

If you'd like to collect this field, I'd recommend using Elements, which allows a param to be passed in as part of `stripe.createToken`

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#stripe-create-token